# connect method of react breaking my test case

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, reactjs, mocha.js

- I am trying to write the test case for my jsx file...
- i took the sample test case from another jsx file...
- that file doesnt have connect method...
- but his file has connect method..
- I think because of this its breaking my test case...
- can you guys tell me how to fix it..
- providing my code below...
- clear code below
  **https://gist.github.com/js08/d590e78e8923e68b191a**

---

SyntaxError: C:/codebase/sports/test/sports-tests.js: Unexpected token (20:73)
  18 |
  19 |     it('should render correctly', () => {

> 20 |         shallowRenderer.render();
>        |                                                                          ^
>     21 |         /*let renderedElement = shallowRenderer.getRenderOutput();
>     22 |

```
test case
import {expect} from 'chai';
import React from 'react';
import TestUtils from 'react-addons-test-utils';
import sportsPageDefault from '../src/sports-Page-Default';
import initializeJsDom from './test-utils/dom.js';
import {getGridLayoutClasses} from 'sports-css-grids';
//import _difference from 'lodash/array/difference';


describe('shallow renderer tests for sports-Page-Default ', function() {
    let shallowRenderer = TestUtils.createRenderer();
    console.log("shallowRenderer" + JSON.stringify(shallowRenderer));


    it('should render correctly', () => {
        shallowRenderer.render(<sportsPageDefault headerClass='8887' layout= {id: 100, text: 'hello world'} sidebar= {id: 100, text: 'hello world'} title="Demo" />);
        let renderedElement = shallowRenderer.getRenderOutput();
        console.log(renderedElement);

       /* let actualTitleEl = renderedElement.props.children[0].props.children[0];
        let expectedTitleEl = <h1 className="transactionalPageHeader-appName font-serif">Demo</h1>;
        expect(actualTitleEl).to.deep.equal(expectedTitleEl);*/
    });



});

actual code

import './css/sports-bottom-layout.css';
import './css/sports-Page.css';
import './css/sports-leftCornerLayout.css';

import React from 'react';
import PageHeader from './components/page-header/page-header';
import MainContent from './components/main-content';
import sports-bottom-layout from './components/sports-bottom-layout/sports-bottom-layout';
import {getPanelLayoutState} from './util/PageLayout';
import {getGridLayoutClasses} from 'sports-css-grids/lib/js/gridLayout';
import PagePureRenderMixin from './util/PagePureRenderMixin';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {setHeaderPanelState, setRightPanelState} from './redux/layout/layout-actions';

console.log("inside");
let customMixin = PagePureRenderMixin({
    state: {
        mainPanelGridClassList: function(classArray) {
            return classArray.length;
            console.log("classArray.length" + classArray.length);
        }
    }
});

let PT = React.PropTypes;

let sportsPageDefault = React.createClass({


    propTypes: {
        headerClass: React.PropTypes.string,
        layout: PT.object.isRequired,
        sports-leftCornerLayout: PT.oneOfType([
            PT.func,
            PT.object
        ]),
        title: PT.string.isRequired
    },


    //cpomponent m,ount code

});

function sportsShallow(itemA, itemB) {
    for (let i in itemA) {
        if (itemA[i] !== itemB[i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

export default connect(state => ({
    layout: state.Page.layout
}))(sportsPageDefault);
```

Error: 
    ts throwing an error since not sure how to pass in onof types for function....

```
shallowRenderer.render(<sportsPageDefault headerClass='8887' layout= {{id: 100, text: 'hello world'}} sidebar= {[{onAppExit},{id: 100, text: 'hello world'}]} title={"Demo"} />);

    propTypes: {
        headerClass: React.PropTypes.string,
        layout: PT.object.isRequired,
        sports-leftCornerLayout: PT.oneOfType([
            PT.func,
            PT.object
        ]),
        title: PT.string.isRequired
    },
TypeError: Cannot read property 'propTypes' of undefined
at [object Object].ReactCompositeComponentMixin._processProps (\node_modules\react\lib\ReactCompositeComponent.js:352:20)
at [object Object].ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent (\node_modules\react\lib\ReactCompositeComponent.js:129:28)
at [object Object].wrapper as mountComponent
at [object Object].ReactShallowRenderer._render (\node_modules\react\lib\ReactTestUtils.js:362:14)
at [object Object].ReactShallowRenderer.render (\node_modules\react\lib\ReactTestUtils.js:344:8)
at Context. (C:/codebase/usaa-template-standard/test/usaa-template-standard-tests.js:23:25)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start by cleaning up your code a bit, it looks like a mess; you have some characters in there that would break your code but I assume you put for presentation purposes, and putting all the code into one code block makes it look very wrong.

Regardless, there is the big real issue that most people have when trying to test `connect`ed `react-redux` components. There is beautiful documentation in their library explaining a great way to test them, I'll summarize.

You can't render a connected component unless there is a `Provider` in an ancestor. You could always render one of those in your tests but the recommended solution is to export both the connected and not connected components. In your case, you would do it like this:

```
export let sportsPageDefault = React.createClass({
    propTypes: {
        headerClass: React.PropTypes.string,
        layout: PT.object.isRequired,
        sports-leftCornerLayout: PT.oneOfType([
            PT.func,
            PT.object
        ]),
        title: PT.string.isRequired
    },
});

export default connect(state => ({
    layout: state.Page.layout
}))(sportsPageDefault);
```

Notice that I'm exporting a default as well as the class itself. This allows you to import the component the usual way in your production code, but in your tests, import as follows:

```
import { sportsPageDefault } from 'path/to/component';
```

What we do here is imported the not connected component. You have now decoupled redux from your component.

That error you're getting is hard to pinpoint given the state of your code. If you clean it up and provide more info we might be able to help, but this is a good starting point to testing redux components.

Comment: thanks for your reply...but how to fix the syntax error https://gist.github.com/js08/5b27a90024a5bf85ab45

Comment: in that gist you posted, literally the little arrow is pointing at your syntax error. Remove that curly since you need it after the equal sign, not before `layout`

Comment: thanks for your reply...but how to pass for function as it as  one of the types...now its showing proptypes undefined error '        shallowRenderer.render(<sportsPageDefault headerClass='8887' layout= {{id: 100, text: 'hello world'}} sidebar= {[{onAppExit},{id: 100, text: 'hello world'}]} title={"Demo"} />);
'

Comment: not sure what you mean by "pass for function" also undefined where exactly?

Comment: not sure why you're getting that error, could you try reducing the size of your example and isolating what you think might be wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106478/discussion-between-texi-rv-and-zekedroid).